# indecomposable summand

Tags: commutative-algebra, modules, dedekind-domain

Let $M$ be an $R$ module. Is this true for start a proof that we say "Let $S$ denote the indecomposable summands of $M$"?

In fact,

> I want to know whether any module over a Dedekind domain (or a DVR) has an indecomposable summand.

Thanks.

Comment: It is not true for start to say "Let S denote the indecomposable summands of M" since we dont know if S is empty or not?

Comment: Does each module has idecomposable decomposition?

Comment: Any finitely generated module over a Dedekind domain is the direct sum of indecomposable modules.